# Is it possible to pause C program inside SIGSEGV handler for further investigation?

Tags: c, debugging, exception, gdb, signals

I'm currently preparing my application for more real-world testing in order to catch all super rare and hard to reproduce edge cases. I've already installed SIGSEGV handler that prints backtrace to log file however it doesn't provide all data I would like to get.

I would prefer my program to stop execution (something like sending -STOP signal) when program crashes, so that I could attach QtCreator with gdb to it while it's still alive and check current variables in all threads active during crash, across whole stacktrace.

```c
void MessFS_sigsegvHandler(int sig) {
  void *array[20];
  size_t size;

  size = backtrace(array, 20);
  MessLog_log(MESS_LOG_ERROR,MESS_LOG_ERROR, "[Core] Critical error: unexpected signal (%d):\n", sig);
  backtrace_symbols_fd(array, size, 1);
  exit(1);               // i would like to pause here instead of terminate
}
```

Is it possible? If it is - will it be possible to attach debugger to such paused process?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a core dump - that dumps the whole memory of the process to a file that can be explored with gdb. There's lots of info on the web about enabling core dumps on segfault (not sure whether having a handler interferes or not)

Comment: that was good idea. I combined it with `pause()` so now I'm calling `pause()` and additionally before that I'm preparing to generate coredump when app will be killed with `SIGABRT`. It's actually FUSE filesystem so I preferred pausing in order to be able to observe other apps using filesystem which could lead to failure (when fs is paused they just hang while if it crashes they will just continue operation after receiving `ENOTCONN`

Comment: You might also want to look into the third parameter passed to sigaction() style handlers (the sa_handler type), which contains a copy of the interrupted process's register state.  See 'man sigaction', 'man setcontext', and <ucontext.h>.
Declaring your signal()-registered handler with 3 parameters usually also provides access.

Answer (score 0):

> I would prefer my program to stop execution

You can call `sleep()` with large enough number of seconds to sleep. `sleep()` can be safely used in signal handler. According to [man signal-safety](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html), it should be async-signal-safe by POSIX.1.